# Parse push getting delayed in real device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

My application working fine in emulator and notifications receiving with minimum or no delay. But in real devices its getting delayed.Tested with many devices,for some its taking only minutes, for other it taking huge delay. Also tried with signed APK file. I have no idea why this delay is happening.Please help me to resole this problem.

Comment: We have seen similar results on the older devices (4.2.1). Our pushes then get delayed if you turn wifi off & then on again. I think this may be a bug in GCM rather than parse, but have nothing concrete on it. We workaround the issue by doing an occasional polling call as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think your are testing using WIFI connection cause of that its happening, just move to 3g connection and check how fast is it.

Comment: Tried with both, mobile data and WiFi.